# App crashes with no exception or crash log

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

My app crashes, but generates no exception in the console and no crash log on the device. No memory warnings are received. Is there any way I can narrow down the cause without having to comment out code?

Comment: Maybe try to add a exception handler : http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/handling-unhandled-exceptions-and.html

Comment: Start adding NSLog() in AppDelegate or set the first breakpoint in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method and step from there.

Comment: Could you provide more information? E.g. does this happen when Xcode is attached in debugging mode? Simulator or device only crash? Does the app start? Does it crash after some time, on some user action. Usually a crash log is not generated if Xcode is attached with the debugger or if the app gets killed because of either excessive memory consumption or the watchdog found it to take too long for startup, shutdown, and some more variants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the crash was that I was logging a really large array with NSLog - did not know that could crash an app!

Comment: Good to know, you should validate your answer and maybe edit the subject to be more specific

Answer (score 0):

Stepping through the code should help you nail down where the app is crashing, this will stop the program execution before it hits any "bad" code (providing you put the breakpoint - where the code will stop in the right place).  You can add a break point by clicking on the appropriate line number to the left of the code editing pane and can access the break points organiser through the View->Navigators->Show Breakpoint Navigators menu.

You may have some inkling of the method or class that's currently being executed in which case you should put a break point on the first line of that method, if the class is a UIViewController then putting the break point on the first line of it's -(void)viewDidLoad method may help.  You could, at a push, put your breakpoint on the first line of -(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching in the application delegate.  However this will require a lot of stepping into instructions rather than just stepping over instructions.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html

Apple also suggest turning on the static analyser and then inferring problems in your code from it's output.